# PHP change date format

Tags: php, date

I have date from monthpicker in this format: 2014 April , and i want to change it to 2014-04-01 before inserting it to mysql.
I'm trying to use strtotime:

```
$b = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['month']));
echo $b;
```

Result is: 1970-01-01. I dont get it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$date = new DateTime("2014 April");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y F', '2014 April');
echo $date->format('Y-m-01');
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are `month` is being parsed incorrectly.

Try echoing `strtotime($_POST['month'])` - you will probably see a result of `0`.

Try using `DateTime` function too,

```
$date = new DateTime("2014 April");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [strptime("date","format")](http://php.net/strptime) - you can use same format as in date()

Answer (score 0):

you can Use `strtotime()` and `date()`for PHP change date format:

```
$originalDate = "2014-04-06";
$yourDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```